# Excel's clipboard Text Import Wizard does not replicate delimited format when recorded in a Macro

Tags: excel, text, import, wizard, vba

I am importing a text from clipboard using TIW and delimited settings. This works fine manually. When I record the macro it simply pastes the data, no delimited functionality.

Is this a known issue or am I missing something. Google/Stack search does not seem to discuss the issue - though some discussion on a traditional File>Open>CSV import.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: This is not a programming related question...

Answer (score 1):

In your macro you need to include this: (with specific true or false statement for yours needs)

```
   ..... ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=True, Comma:=True, _
     Space:=True, Other:=True, OtherChar:="?" ......
```

BTW. can you write a code from macro

Comment: Thank you very much, you're a star. Much appreciated!